# openerp function field not working - OpenERP v7

Tags: odoo

I am having issues with getting a function field to display a string returned by a function in a custom module I am using to extend the stock.picking.out form. Ideally I would like to have a specific string from a field stored in the database displayed but that's an issue for another time because I can't even get a generic string to display..

Here is my field definition within my custom class:

```
_columns = {
    'my_field_name': fields.function(_my_func, type='char', string='description', store=True, method=True, readonly=True),
}
```

Here is my definition for '_my_func':

```
def _my_func(self, cr, uid, ids, field_name, arg, context=None):
    str="some string to be displayed"
    return str
```

Here is the XML for the field:

```
<field name="my_field_name" string="Here is my string:" class="oe_inline"/>
```

I have searched the OpenERP dev book as well as their forums and these forums, and believe I have followed all of the proper syntax for this field so any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to improve your function/method like,

```
def _my_func(self, cr, uid, ids, field_name, arg, context=None):
    res = {}
    for rec in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
        res[rec.id] = 'Some string'
    return res
```

while writing functional field(up to v7) make sure you return a dictionary like

```
{17: "some string"}
```

if you have multiple field it can be like

```
{17: {'field_one': 'value 1', 'field_two': 'value 1'}}
```

EDIT:
Also In `_columns` please remove `readonly=True` like

```
_columns = {
    'my_field_name': fields.function(_my_func, type='char', string='description', store=True, method=True),
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried everyone's answer (as they were all almost identical to one another) and my field still is not displaying the string, is my python code for the field correct? Thanks for helping out!

Comment: @nick Oh. You made the field readonly. check my updated answer.

Comment: Readonly shouldn't interfere with your answer. OpenERP V7 function fields are readonly by default, as long as there is no inverse function defined on it. I think his problem is what many others had so far: stock.picking.out. Try out attempt 3 of guewen found [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/openobject-addons/+bug/1169998/comments/4). Define the fields on stock.picking and stock.picking.out (for easiest use, define them exact the same). Hope this helps

Comment: Can you put a hint on this problem into your answer @AtulArvind ? He has to use V7, so he should know that this will cause some problems ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Just you must have to improve your function login

you can do some things like this.

```
def _my_func(self, cr, uid, ids, field_name, arg, context=None)
    v={}
    if field_name:
        v['my_field_name'] = " some string to be displayed "
    return {'value': v}
```

Then finally your function logic working like a charm.

I hope this should helpful for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try following,

```
def _my_func(self, cr, uid, ids, field_name, arg, context=None):
    res = {}
    for obj in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
        ###Set your string here
        str="some string to be displayed"
        res[obj.id]['my_field_name'] =  str

    return res
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are a little confused with OpenERP v7, you always can try with Odoo(OpenERP v8) It's much more easiest to work.

```
from openerp import models, fields,api
```

class my_class(models.Model):

```
_name="my.class"
my_field_name=fields.Text(string="description", compute=_my_func, store=True, readonly=True)

def _my_func(self):
    self.my_field_name = "some string to be displayed"
```

I hope this can help you!

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I can't use v8 though

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
def _my_func(self, cr, uid, ids, field_name, arg, context=None):
    result = {}
    for record in self.browse(cr, uid, ids):
        str="some string to be displayed"
        result[record.id] = str
    return result
```

and if you use store = True on a functional-field then it will be accessed for the first time and it will store the result in database, and from next time it wont be called.
To access functional field every time for  **store = True** , refer  **sale.py [amount_total]**  field. We have to write some addtional code

Answer (score 0):

You can give like this also :

without using browse method..

```
def _my_func(self, cr, uid, ids, field_name, arg, context=None):
    result = {}
    str="some string to be displayed"
    result[ids[0]] = str
    return result
```

Make sure, in model field type should be char/text.